# how to pass a values from the database to the json in php

Tags: php

Thanks in advance, I have a three salary data in the table column. I am using while loop to display three salary values in the view page. But I have to pass these three values to three variables in json like {salary1:$sal1,salary2:$sal2,salary3:$sal3}. How to seperate looped three salary values into three variables

```
My code as below:

<table border="1">
        <caption><h2>View Registration</h2></caption>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Designation</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        <tr>
          <?php

            include('common.php');
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from register"); 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {

          ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['designation']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td> 
          <td><?php

           $salary = $row['salary'];      
           echo $salary; 


           ?></td>
        <tr>
          <?php
           }         


          ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: did you json_encode when you save the value id database, now you can use json_decode , it return array, from this array you can access this

Comment: use `json_decode($salary, TRUE)`

Comment: No, just if I seperate the looped three salary values into three variable is enough

Comment: when you save salary make it like 
$salary = array(
      'salary1'=>$sal1,
      'salary2'=>$sal2,
      'salary3'=>$sal3
); 

$salary = jason_encode($salary) and insert it into database

Comment: Actually i am inserting the salary from HTML textbox individually for different employees so in database it is stored in a different 3 rows. Just if I split the looped values into three variables is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array of all salary and echo with json_encode, array will be convert in to json as you wants,

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from register");

$salary =array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $salary[$row['name']] = $row['salary'];
}
echo json_encode($salary);
```

Comment: You code is working fine .Instead of salry1,salary2 actually in json I have to pass like this {mohan:15000, Keshav:30000,vimal:35000} like this

Comment: I have updated the code with name of employee as key @Ragith Thomas

Comment: Like this "data": [
          {
              "label": "Mohan",
              "value":  "15000",

          },
          {
              "label": "Keshav",
              "value": "30000",
          },
          {
              "label": "Vimal",
              "value": "35000" ,
          },

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
        <caption><h2>View Registration</h2></caption>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Designation</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        <tr>
          <?php

            include('common.php');
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from register"); 
            $arraySalary=array();// declaring an array for json array
            $loopCounter=1;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {

          ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['designation']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td> 
          <td><?php

           $salary = $row['salary'];
           $arraySalary['salary'.$loopCounter]= $row['salary'];    // making an array os diffrent index as salry1, salary2, salary3.
           $loopCounter++;
           ?></td>
        <tr>
          <?php
           }  
           echo json_encode($arraySalary);  // here you will get the salary json.     


          ?>
      </table>
```

Please have a try on this. I have checked this. and working fine.